# Prove that six conditions on natural number $n$ are all logically equivalent.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

In studying a course on propositional logic, I ran into the following problem.

Prove that the following conditions on the natural number $n$ are all (logically) equivalent. Use as few conditional proofs as possible.

1. $n$ is divisible by 3
2. $n^2$ is divisible by 3
3. $n^2$ is divisible by 9
4. $n^3$ is divisible by 3
5. $n^3$ is divisible by 9
6. $n^3$ is divisible by 27

We need to prove that each statement has an "if and only if" (ie a material biconditional) relationship with each of the other statements.

Using as few conditional proofs as possible means that we should prove one "cycle", for example:

$$1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 4 \implies 5 \implies 6 \implies 1$$

**My question is how to do this.**

Here is my attempt.

$6 \implies 5$

if $n^3$ divisible by 27 then $n^3=27m=3\times9m$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $n^3$ is divisible by 9.

$5 \implies 4$

if $n^3$ divisible by 9 then $n^3=3^2m, m \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore n^3 divisible by 3.

$4 \implies 3$

$3 \implies 2$

$n^2$ divisible by 9 then $n^2=3^2m, m \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore $n^2$ divisible by 3.

$2 \implies 1$

$n^2$ divisible by 3, then $n^2=3m, m \in \mathbb{N}$

Assume $m$ is not divisible by 3. Then $n=\sqrt{3m}$, which is not a perfect square, so $n \notin \mathbb{N}$, but this contradicts our premise that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $m$ is divisible by 3, so $n^2=3^2k, k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $n=3k$, divisible by 3.

$1 \implies 6$
$n$ divisible by 3 then $n=3m, m \in \mathbb{N}$. $n^3 = 27m$. Therefore, $n^3$ is divisible by 27.

**Is this proof correct (with exception of the missing step $4 \implies 3$)?**
**What is the proof of the missing step?**

Answer (score 1):

> $1 \implies 6$
>  $n$ divisible by 3 then $n=3m, m \in \mathbb{N}$.
> $n^3 = 27m$. Therefore, $n^3$ is divisible by 27.

You forgot to cube the $m;$ fortunately, this doesn't affect what follows.

> $2 \implies 1$
>  $n^2$ divisible by 3, then
> $n^2=3m, m \in \mathbb{N}.$ Assume $m$ is not divisible by 3.
> Then $n=\sqrt{3m}$,
> which is not a perfect square, so $n \notin \mathbb{N}$, but this
> contradicts our premise that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $m$ is
> divisible by 3, so $n^2=3^2k, k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $n=3k$, divisible
> by 3.

The final $k$ needs to be square-rooted, in which case it's no longer clear that $n$ is divisible by $3.$

If a prime number $p$ divides a perfect square $n^2,$ then, for some integer $q,$ $$n^2=p^2q^2.$$

> 3. $n^2$ is divisible by 9
> 4. $n^3$ is divisible by 3
>
> $4 \implies 3$

If a prime number $p$ divides a perfect cube $n^3,$ then, for some integer $q,$ $$n^3=p^3q^3.$$

Comment: "If a prime number $p$ divides a perfect square $n^2$, then, for some integer $q$, $n^2=p^2q^2". Is this a Theorem?

Comment: @evianpring It might be a corollary of the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: How do you get from $n^3=3^3q^3$ to $n^2$ is divisible by 9? $n^2=3^3q^3 \frac{1}{n}$. $\frac{1}{n}$ is not a natural number, and we don't know the relationship between it and $q$.

Comment: @evianpring Take the first equation in your last comment, and raise both sides to the power $2/3.$